# How to create a python class contains empty list, add points to it, and return cordinates of points as tuple

Tags: python, class, oop, points

I need some help in python oop, I want to create an empty list as an instance in a python class, then add a method that appends points in that empty list, and add a string method that returns the coordinates of all points, like ( x1,y1) (x2,y2) (x3,y3 ) . . . (xn,yn )
here is my code but it's not working:

```
class Foo:

    # This list is initially empty
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = []
        
    # append_point method which takes a point as an argument and  
    # adds points to the instance variable.
    def append_point(self, **point):
        self.lst.append(point)
        return tuple(self.lst)
    # returns the coordinates of all points
    def __str__(self):
        return f'cordinates : {self.lst}'

if __name__ == '__main__':

    cor = Foo([1,2,4,3,5,7])
    print(cor)
```

Comment: You need to make `lst` optional argument, e.g. `def __init__(self, lst=None):`. Then `if lst is None` - initialize with empty list, otherwise bind `lst` that you pass to `self.lst`. Your current code just ignores the list you pass as argument

Answer (score 0):

```
class Points:
    def __init__(self, points=None):
        if points is None:
            points = []
        self.points = points
        
    def add_point(self, point):
        self.points.append(point)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Points coordinates: {self.points}'
    
points = Points([(0,0),(0,1)])
points.add_point((1,1))

print(points)
```

Output:

```
Points coordinates: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's Perfect